# Can I clean up multiple child processes with the same parent using wait(&status) and loop in C?

Tags: c, process, fork, wait, system-calls

I am writing a program that can read the `linux` commands from a file and run them parallelly using `fork()` and `execvp()` and it works fine.

```
 while((current = GetNextCommand(current)) != NULL){
            char currentCommand[WIDTH - 1];
            current->active = true;
            strcpy(currentCommand, current->command);
            int j=0;
            int ctr=0;
            char newString[LENGTH][WIDTH];
            for(int i = 0; i <= strlen(currentCommand); i++){
                // if space or NULL found, assign NULL into newString[ctr]
                if(currentCommand[i]==' '|| currentCommand[i]=='\0')
                {
                    newString[ctr][j]='\0';
                    ctr++;  //for next word
                    j=0;    //for next word, init index to 0
                }
                else
                {
                    newString[ctr][j] = currentCommand[i];
                    j++;
                }
            }
            char *exe[ctr + 1];
            for(int i = 0; i < ctr; i++){
                exe[i] = strdup(newString[i]);
            }
            exe[ctr] = NULL;
            t = clock();
            clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &start);
            current->starttime = start.tv_sec;
            current->PID = (pid = fork());
            if(pid < 0){
                fprintf(stderr, "fork Failed\n"); //output in stderr if fork fails and return
                exit(1);
            }
            else if(pid == 0){
                execvp(exe[0], exe);
                //fails
                exit(2);
            }
        }
```

My file is

```
sleep 3
ls -latr
sleep 1
pwd
sleep 1
wc /etc/passwd
sleep 10
```

In the parent process, I need to get the running time of each child process and rerun the command if the running time of a command is greater than 2 seconds. If the running time of a command is greater than 2, I will keep running it until the user kills the process using `kill -sig pid` or `pkill sleep`. I use a for loop and set the corresponding numbers of wait(&status). In my file, `sleep 3` and `sleep 10` will be greater than 2 seconds. When the process of `sleep 3` has done its work, it will return to the parent and `sleep 10` is still running. When I use `pkill sleep` now, it will be fine because `sleep 10` will continue running in the parent process. However, when both of them exit from the child process and I use `kill -sig pid`, the whole program quit. Thus, how can I run them (`sleep 3` and `sleep 10`) concurrently in this situation?

```
for(int i = 0; i < nodeIndex - 1; i++){
    int status;
    int pid = wait(&status);
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &finish);
    CommandNode* cNode;
    cNode = FindCommand(head->nextCommandPtr, pid);
    elapsed = finish.tv_sec - cNode->starttime;
    printf("%ld\n", elapsed);
    if(elapsed < 2){
        cNode->active = false;
    }
    else{
        char rerunCommand[WIDTH - 1];
        strcpy(rerunCommand, cNode->command);
        int j=0;
        int ctr=0;
        char newString[LENGTH][WIDTH];
        for(int i = 0; i <= strlen(rerunCommand); i++){
            // if space or NULL found, assign NULL into newString[ctr]
            if(rerunCommand[i]==' '|| rerunCommand[i]=='\0')
            {
                newString[ctr][j]='\0';
                ctr++;  //for next word
                j=0;    //for next word, init index to 0
            }
            else
            {
                newString[ctr][j] = rerunCommand[i];
                j++;
            }
        }
        char *exe[ctr + 1];
        for(int i = 0; i < ctr; i++){
            exe[i] = strdup(newString[i]);
        }
        exe[ctr] = NULL;
        while(elapsed > 2){
            int pid2;
            t = clock();
            clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &start);
            cNode->starttime = start.tv_sec;
            cNode->PID = (pid2 = fork());
            if(pid2 < 0){
                fprintf(stderr, "fork Failed"); //output in stderr if fork fails and return
                exit(1);
            }
            else if(pid2 == 0){
                printf("What happened here.\n");
                execvp(exe[0], exe);
                exit(2);
            }
            else{
                wait(&status);
                clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &finish);
                elapsed = finish.tv_sec - cNode->starttime;
                if(elapsed > 2) {
                    printf("What is this: %d %d\n", pid2, cNode->PID);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: suggest change your icon picture

Comment: regarding: `for(int i = 0; i <= strlen(rerunCommand); i++){`  This probably will not work as expected.  This is because in C, the valid index into an array is [0...number elements in array-1]  Suggest using: `for(int i = 0; i < strlen(rerunCommand); i++){`

Comment: for each call to `strdup()` that is successful, there (eventually) needs to be a call to `free()` with the same pointer

Comment: regarding: `printf("What happened here.\n");
                execvp(exe[0], exe);
                exit(2);`   1) the child process is executing, that is what happened.  2)  This is the syntax for `execvp()`  Notice the second parameter is a pointer to an array of pointers, not a pointer to a string `int execvp(const char *file, char *const argv[]);` 3) the `execvp()` function only returns if an error occurred, so should be followed by: `perror( "execvp failed" );` followed by `exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`

Comment: regarding: `cNode->PID = (pid2 = fork());`  This will assign `true` or `false` into `cNode->PID`  Perhaps you meant: `cNode->PID = pid2 = fork();`

Comment: Please post a [mcve] so we can reproduce the problem and help you debug it.

Comment: @user3629249 Thank you for your help, but the above code works fine. My problem is that how I can run `sleep 3` and `sleep 10` concurrently when both of them return to the parent process.

Comment: the posted code does not contain: `sleep(3)` nor a `sleep(10)`  Please post a [mcve] so we can reproduce the problem and help you debug it.

Answer (score 0):

regarding the question in the title:

Yes you can, just loop until the returned value is -1

Comment: I am sorry that my title is vague. I think you mean using a while loop and wait(&status) instead of a for a loop and this will make sure `sleep 3` and `sleep 10` concurrently. Is that current? It causes the segmentation fault.

Comment: calling `waitpid()` should NEVER cause a seg fault event.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, indeed this is a correct way of ensure that all your children have finished before you continue:

```
pid_t pid;
...
while((pid = wait(NULL)) >= 0)
    printf("child pid=%d ended.\n", pid); /* or whatever you want */

/* no more children active after this point, you don't need 
 * to check the value of errno, except if you allow this
 * process to be interrupted by a signal. */
```

This is the old legacy of the zombie processes (like a title for a walking dead movie):  A zombie process is a process that has `exit(2)`ed and which parent has not `wait(2)`ed for.  It has all its resources freed, except its process table entry (in which its exit code and accounting records are stored).  In this way, when the parent does a `wait(2)` system call, the kernel can navigate the table of its children processes and check if it has to return an error (if the list is empty), or there's some child that has ended and can return its `exit(2)` code to the parent.  You can only use `wait(2)` properly (e.g. without errors) if you have previously made a `fork(2)`, and `wait(2)` signals an error in case you have created no child processes.

To get the running time of the children, you need to use one of the alternate syscalls to `wait(2)` (`wait3(2)` or `wait4(2)`, as per FreeBSD manual page, on linux there are similar syscalls)

Try this simple example:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define N                    7
#define PARENT_SLEEP        30
#define CHILD_MAXSLEEP      60

int main()
{
    int i;
    pid_t mypid = getpid();

    for(i = 0; i < N; i++) {

        pid_t chpid = fork();

        switch (chpid) {

        case -1: /* error */
            fprintf(stderr,
                "Parent [pid=%d]: fork: %s\n",
                mypid,
                strerror(errno));
            goto out; /* we want to break the loop */

        case 0: /* child */
            /* reinit mypid to reflect proper value */
            mypid = getpid();

            printf("Child [pid=%d]: start\n", mypid);

            /* we initialize random module after fork, so
             * all children don't get the same random
             * sequence. Probably all of them will take
             * the same value for the time, so we use also
             * the pid for the seed to be different for
             * each child. */
            srandom( mypid ^ time(NULL) );

            /* a random time between 1 and CHILD_MAXSLEEP */
            int myrandom = random() % CHILD_MAXSLEEP + 1;
            printf("Child [pid=%d]: wait for %d secs.\n",
                    mypid, myrandom);
            sleep( myrandom );

            printf("Child [pid=%d]: exiting with code=%d\n",
                mypid, myrandom);
            exit( myrandom );

        default: /* parent */
            printf("Parent[pid=%d]: I have started"
                    " child (pid = %d)\n", mypid, chpid);
            break;
        } /* switch */
    } /* for */

out:
    /* if you put a delay here, before doing wait()s,
     * and you execute a ps(1) command before the parent
     * begins to make waits, and some of the children have
     * already died, you'll see the zombie processes
     * (they are marked with a Z in status) */
    printf("Parent [pid=%d]: sleeping for %ds.\n",
            mypid, PARENT_SLEEP);
    sleep(PARENT_SLEEP);
    printf("Parent [pid=%d]: beginning to wait.\n",
            mypid);

    int status;
    pid_t child;

    while ((child = wait(&status)) >= 0) {
        printf("Parent[pid=%d]: "
                "detected exit(%d) from "
                "child(pid=%d)\n",
                mypid,
                WEXITSTATUS(status),
                child);
    }

    printf("Parent[pid=%d]: exiting\n", mypid);

    exit(0);

} /* main */
```

and one example of one execution:

```
$ a.out
Parent[pid=81452]: I have started child (pid = 81453)
Parent[pid=81452]: I have started child (pid = 81454)
Parent[pid=81452]: I have started child (pid = 81455)
Parent[pid=81452]: I have started child (pid = 81456)
Child [pid=81453]: start
Child [pid=81453]: wait for 34 secs.
Child [pid=81455]: start
Child [pid=81455]: wait for 56 secs.
Child [pid=81456]: start
Child [pid=81456]: wait for 42 secs.
Parent[pid=81452]: I have started child (pid = 81457)
Parent[pid=81452]: I have started child (pid = 81458)
Parent[pid=81452]: I have started child (pid = 81459)
Parent [pid=81452]: sleeping for 30s.
Child [pid=81454]: start
Child [pid=81454]: wait for 9 secs.
Child [pid=81457]: start
Child [pid=81457]: wait for 58 secs.
Child [pid=81458]: start
Child [pid=81458]: wait for 30 secs.
Child [pid=81459]: start
Child [pid=81459]: wait for 14 secs.
Child [pid=81454]: exiting with code=9
Child [pid=81459]: exiting with code=14
Child [pid=81458]: exiting with code=30
Parent [pid=81452]: beginning to wait.   <<<<< before this message, you can see Zombie processes.
Parent[pid=81452]: detected exit(14) from child(pid=81459)
Parent[pid=81452]: detected exit(30) from child(pid=81458)
Parent[pid=81452]: detected exit(9) from child(pid=81454)
Child [pid=81453]: exiting with code=34
Parent[pid=81452]: detected exit(34) from child(pid=81453)
Child [pid=81456]: exiting with code=42
Parent[pid=81452]: detected exit(42) from child(pid=81456)
Child [pid=81455]: exiting with code=56
Parent[pid=81452]: detected exit(56) from child(pid=81455)
Child [pid=81457]: exiting with code=58
Parent[pid=81452]: detected exit(58) from child(pid=81457)
Parent[pid=81452]: exiting
$ _
```